# Parsing a java.io.File into JSON using GSON

Tags: java, json

I'm sending a file over the network which is in JSON format and wanting to retrieve information from it. The file is created using the `File.createTempFile` method. Here's the code:

```
File patchFile = File.createTempFile("indexer", ".pf", null);
try(FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(patchFile)) {
    byte[] patchFileBytes = new byte[payloadLength];
    buffer.readBytes(patchFileBytes);
    fos.write(patchFileBytes);
}
```

I'm trying to find the best way to read the `patchFile` as JSON and get values from it. The generated files structure looks like this(on the client):

```
{
  "0": [
    {
      "fileId": "Cache.dat",
      "fileChecksum": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
    },
    {
      "fileId": "Character.fbx",
      "fileChecksum": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
    },
    {
      "fileId": "Skybox.png",
      "fileChecksum": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"
    }
  ],
  "1": [
    {
      "fileId": "indexer.pf",
      "fileChecksum": "f8130e38ce5c58ccbf200d24c2629632"
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently I've got the file being sent over and read into memory as you can see above, but I'm unsure as to where to go from here on actually reading the data, could anyone help me out?

I'm using **GSON**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would suggest is to avoid writing to a temporary file, instead wrap the buffer with a reader and use in one of the API's
(I'm assuming that the buffer is an InputStream, then use java.io.InputStreamReader to convert it into a Reader)

GSON has a lot of API's to perform your required task:

**Examples:**

To follow the iterative approach, then look at `com.google.gson.JsonParser#parse` it accepts reader or string to get elements.

If you know what is the type of the element being deserialized, then you can look at using `com.google.gson.Gson#fromJson` methods.

See the following API docs, it might be helpful:
[JsonStreamParser](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonStreamParser.html)
[JsonParser](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonParser.html)
[Gson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention how big your file can be. If it is not too big then you could just use Apache Commons IO and [IOUtils.toString](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) and read the entire file content into String. And since you already know GSON it should be pretty simple from there.

Comment: The file can be virtually any size, depends on the amount of files indexed.

Comment: Then the approach suggested by MJSG is much better.